# How can i reactive list entities with different params in Quarkus 3.0.0.RC2 with hibernate reactive panache library while using repository pattern?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive

I am working on a project using Quarkus 3.0.0.CR2 and Hibernate Reactive Panache as the ORM for a reactive application. The application retrieves animals from owners using an API [resource](https://github.com/Lukec1/quarkus-3.0.0.CR2-sample/blob/main/src/main/java/org/acme/ZooResource.java) that makes 5 reactive calls to a [service](https://github.com/Lukec1/quarkus-3.0.0.CR2-sample/blob/main/src/main/java/org/acme/ZooService.java), which is forwards to the [database repository implementation](https://github.com/Lukec1/quarkus-3.0.0.CR2-sample/blob/main/src/main/java/org/acme/ZooRepository.java).

However, when reapeatably running the [unit test](https://github.com/Lukec1/quarkus-3.0.0.CR2-sample/blob/main/src/test/java/org/acme/ZooResourceTest.java) or making curl calls to "http://localhost:8080/zoo/animals/Melani", I am randomly encountering two different errors:

- `org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session/EntityManager is closed`
- `org.hibernate.HibernateException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException`

Could someone please help me understand why I am encountering these errors and suggest a solution?

Here is a link to a sample project on Github that demonstrates the error: https://github.com/Lukec1/quarkus-3.0.0.CR2-sample

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

By design **hibernate reactive** can not share a session on parallel threads which is blocking using it with Uni or Mutiny.

> The problem is that Hibernate Reactive needs operations on the database to happen in a predictable order to avoid errors when managing entities. So, you cannot share the same session among different threads or uni streams.

> We don't have a solution for this at the moment, and chaining the uni is the only way to be sure that everything will work as expected.

Here is the [real source](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-reactive/issues/1615)

Answer (score 1):

I found solution on Quarkus issues page (https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/28808) and commit solution to existing project(https://github.com/Lukec1/quarkus-3.0.0.CR2-sample/commit/98a4791571334a898716d7780a87d993d443f5c6).

**Edited:** recognized problem is when using Panache Hibernate Reactive and `Uni.combine`. Because of that i now use chain approach which does not work in parallel as we would like with the `Uni.combine`.

ZooService

```java
  public Uni<List<Dog>> getDogs(String owner) {
    return zooRepository.getDogs(owner);
  }

  public Uni<List<Cat>> getCats(String owner) {
    return zooRepository.getCats(owner);
  }

  public Uni<List<Rat>> getRats(String owner) {
    return zooRepository.getRats(owner);
  }

  public Uni<List<Dolphin>> getDoplphins(String owner) {
    return zooRepository.getDoplphins(owner);
  }
```

ZooRepository

```java
private Uni<List<AnimalEntity>> getAnimals(String ownerId, AnimalType animalType) {
    return list("ownerId = ?1 AND animalType = ?2", ownerId, animalType).log()
        .onItem()
        .invoke(
            result ->
                log.debug(
                    "Found {} entities for parameters '{}' - '{}'",
                    result.size(),
                    ownerId,
                    animalType))
        .onFailure()
        .invoke(
            throwable ->
                log.error(
                    "Error while getting accounts for parameters '{}' - '{}'",
                    ownerId,
                    animalType,
                    throwable));
  }

  @WithSession
  public Uni<List<Dog>> getDogs(String ownerId) {
    return getAnimals(ownerId, AnimalType.DOG).map(animalEntityMapper::mapToDogs);
  }

  @WithSession
  public Uni<List<Cat>> getCats(String ownerId) {
    return getAnimals(ownerId, AnimalType.CAT).map(animalEntityMapper::mapToCats);
  }

  @WithSession
  public Uni<List<Rat>> getRats(String ownerId) {
    return getAnimals(ownerId, AnimalType.RAT).map(animalEntityMapper::mapToRats);
  }

  @WithSession
  public Uni<List<Dolphin>> getDoplphins(String ownerId) {
    return getAnimals(ownerId, AnimalType.DOLPHIN).map(animalEntityMapper::mapToDolphins);
  }
```

Code which need to work, but not:

```java
    Uni<List<Dog>> dogs = zooService.getDogs(owner);
    Uni<List<Cat>> cats = zooService.getCats(owner);
    Uni<List<Rat>> rats = zooService.getRats(owner);
    Uni<List<Dolphin>> dolphins = zooService.getDoplphins(owner);
    
    final AnimalsDto summary = new AnimalsDto();
    
    return Uni.combine().all().unis(dogs, cats, rats, 
    dolphins).asTuple().map(animal -> {
         summary.setDogs(animal.getItem1());
         summary.setCats(animal.getItem2());
         summary.setRats(animal.getItem3());
         summary.setDolphins(animal.getItem4());
         return summary;
    });
```

and implemented working solution founded from Quarkus github issues:

```java
     return dogs.invoke(summary::setDogs)
        .chain(() -> cats.invoke(summary::setCats))
        .chain(() -> rats.invoke(summary::setRats))
        .chain(() -> dolphins.invoke(summary::setDolphins))
        .replaceWith(summary);
```

Comment: that code with chains looks like calling dogs and cats sequential not parallel, isn't it the whole idea of using **Uni** to make it all parallel ?

Comment: @ozkanpakdil yes you are right, but i need sadly say for now i don't found other working solution. if anyone has a better solution, especially parallel, I will be extremely happy if they share it with us

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding a code example. Please [edit] to add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that others can confirm that your answer is correct.